# Gimp has no xtns menu in Windows?

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to follow the instructions here and cannot find the xtns menu in the version I'm running of GIMP 2.0:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-gimp-to-batch-edit-your-images-windows-specific-instructions/

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menus moved around in later versions of gimp.  Browse around a bit and you'll see them.